# How to execute a exe on linux using wine with many arguments (openssl x590AT)

Tags: linux, certificate, openssl, wine, ssl-certificate

I need to execute this command in a linux server, i command line using wine:

```
sudo wine /var/myfolder/openssl.exe x509AT -days 355 -AA /var/myfolder/cert/certificate.crt -AAkey /var/myfolder/cert/certkey.key -User /var/myfolder/cert/newcert.crt -out /var/myfolder/cert/newcert-ok.crt -Attribute /var/myfolder/cert/attributes.txt -HolderT 1
```

Wine is not recognizing all arguments.

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: Wine runs some Windows apps, not all, and isn't designed for such usage. And why do you need to run openssl.exe in Linux anyway? https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities

Comment: Firstly, openssl is available for linux.

Comment: Also you could create a batch file and execute it.